# Shopware 6 Staging shows 403 forbidden

Tags: staging, shopware6

I tried to set up a staging of a running Shopware 6 instance.
While I did as the doc of Shopware told, I get a 403 forbidden when I visit the staging like https://staging.xx.de/ I get an 403 error.
The error log says as follows:

```
Cannot serve directory /home/user/xx/staging/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I copied the .htaccess btw.

Answer (score 1):

As the error log states that there could no matching directory index be found, I reckon you pointed your subdomain to the wrong directory. Please make sure you copied Shopware to a subdirectory and your subdomain points to xx.de/{staging}/public/ and that you properly copied any index file to this this directory.